# SQL: Get all columns on MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, razor, max

Using (Webmatrix, MySQL, cshtml/razor)

Hello. I'm trying to get all the values on the row that is the max one, but cant get it to work!

This line gets the max KG, where exerVariName is something.

```
var getData = "SELECT MAX(kg) AS kg FROM Test WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'";
```

This writes it out, tho when I try to write out c.exerVariName it gets error, pretty sure it does that because I only select MAX(kg) from the database and not all (*), so it cant get the other columns.

```
@foreach (var c in db.Query(testData)) {
        <a>@c.exerVariName</a>
        <a>@c.kg</a>
    }
```

So  my question, how do I make it so I can get all the columns values on the row of MAX?

EDIT: Link to image on database https://s29.postimg.org/cbbxfbtxz/pic.png

Comment: post your table structure as well

Comment: to confirm, you want to retrieve all columns for a row, and you want that row to be the max value of the table?

Comment: database is not written in code by myself, provided link to a printscreen of it in my OP!

ye, I want all the values on the row that contains the max value for kg column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return one row with the highest kg.

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM Test
WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'
order by kg desc;
```

But since SQL doesn't guarantee order, if two rows have the same kg there is no guarantee you'll get the same row each time. To guarantee order you could also order by ID like this:

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM Test
WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'
order by kg desc, id;
```

You should replace * with only the columns you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Test  t
WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'
ORDER BY kg DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Gave this error :/    "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 69,Token in error = LIMIT ]"

Comment: @PontusSvedberg . . . Are you not using MySQL?  That is the database in your question and it *definitely* supports `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up this link for the live sample: 
[Fiddler Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7b42/4)

### Sample Code

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`kg` int, `exerVariName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`kg`, `exerVariName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (120, 'test1', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (250, 'test3', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (30, 'other', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;
```

### Query

```
SELECT kg as kg,t.exerVariName FROM   ForgeRock t    
GROUP BY t.exerVariName, kg
HAVING kg =(SELECT  max(kg) FROM   ForgeRock t)
```

Te sample is using MySQL.

Comment: gave error on table name, changed to uppercase T, still error for table name :/

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Test WHERE kg= ( SELECT  MAX(kg) FROM  Test where exerVariName = 'Comp');

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 32,Token in error = SELECT ]

Comment: not sure why, checked everything, all the columnnames are correct with upper/lowercase and everything!

Comment: I have tried and it works fine.Seems like you have used reserved words.